# How to disable the tooltip when drop down box is explode

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Tooltip is showing the selected value of drop down list but if I explode the drop down list and on mouse over to each item it is still showing the selected one.
Hence either i need to disable the tooltip on exploding the drop down list or show the each item value on mouse over the items.
below is my code of the tooltip tag.

```
<rich:tooltip id="srcIdConId" for="serviceId" direction="topRight"
                                        style="font-size: medium;font-style: italic;font-family: sans-serif"
                                        rendered="#{!empty bean.serviceDescCondName}"
                                        value="#{bean.serviceDescCondName}"/>
```